# Cordova/PhoneGap cannot add WP7/WP8/Windows platform

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I got an error while trying to add a wp8 platform on my Win8, see detail as bellow,

~\CordovaWP8>cordova -d platforms add wp8
cordova library for "wp8" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Checking if platform "wp8" passes minimum requirements...
Checking wp8 requirements...
Running ""~.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.1.0\wp8\bin\check_reqs"" (output to follow)

Creating wp8 project...
Running bin/create for platform "wp8" with command: ""~.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.1.0\bin\create"
  "~\CordovaWP8\platforms\wp8" "~\namespace" "CordovaWP8"" (output to follow)

Error: An error occured during creation of wp8 sub-project.
The system cannot find the path specified.

```
at ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\platform.js:246:30
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

But I added an android platform successfully, any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Seems to be a known issue, please see description and fix

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5183

**Solution1. Install prev working version**

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@3.1.0-0.1.0
```

**Solution2. Fix current version.** The following instructions should work

- Navigate to cordova installation folder

~\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\

c:\Users\Sergei\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova

- Replace the following files

src/metadata/wp8_parser.js with https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-cli/blob/181aa1b7e8f3c8b2f7c4db12e1f79d64c26e8b42/src/metadata/wp8_parser.js

src/platform.js with https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-cli/blob/181aa1b7e8f3c8b2f7c4db12e1f79d64c26e8b42/src/platform.js