# phonegap platform not working android

Tags: android, cordova

You can see I have SDK tools installed and the SDK platform installed.

I have no clue why I am getting the error below in the CLI?

I have already created the app, I following http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface getting to the `platform add` step I am failing miserably. Maybe I don't have the android command ? If so how do I do that?

Is it because of administrator access(if so, how do I fix that), is it a path issue(again how do I fix it)?

[image]

I installed `ant` then I went into `C:\Users\visum_000\.cordova\lib` inside there I deleted the android folder, then tried the command again, here is what happened.

You see it downloaded but still gives the error.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you run `android` from the command prompt?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply just now saw this.. when I run `android` the sdk manager pops up then in the command line I get this returned `'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: What is your $PATH environment variable? You should not be getting that error about xcopy - it should be found in your path. Can you just search for xcopy on your machine and see if you have it installed? Mine is in Windows/System32/xcopy.exe. I think it has always been there, so I don't think you'll have to go install it, just fix your PATH.

Comment: Yeah what I did last night was do system restore I think I messed up the existing PATH variables. Then did a fresh install following the docs in order it works now.

Answer (score 0):

It actually looks like you have installed the Android SDK properly on your box. 
Have you adjusted your Path settings and added the Android tools path accordingly ?

Comment: You mean the path variable inside enviorment variables? I did, I set the path to `;C:\Users\visum_000\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools;C:\Users\visum_000\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools` I tried installing SDK inside `C:\Development` I dont think I had access to it not 100% sure, but I tried again inside users\desktop

Comment: That is what you meant? Correct? I am thinking maybe its a permissions problem?

Comment: Anyone have any links, ideas?

Comment: What happens when you type `npm -version` and `node --version`?

Comment: well I just uninstalled cordova, I am using (win8) and sudo is not recognized... So I am thinking re installing it then setting permissions on the folder manually? The version is 3.1.0-0.2.0 . Let me reinstall and type that command in..

Comment: I use win7 so not sure about win8 but pretty sure there isn't really any "sudo". That's for when you run linux based systems and need administrator permission. For Windows, this usually means SHIFT+CLICK and select Run As Administrator. Node and NPM are not Cordova, so uninstalling Cordova won't make a difference with that command.

Comment: I know I looked that up sudo doesnt exist in windows, the reason for the uninstall was not to add sudo to the command (I figure though since I am not using sudo I need to somehow grant permissions), but to follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792936/cordova-phonegap-cannot-add-wp7-wp8-windows-platform and change the cordova version.. I tried solution 2 on that link to no avail.

Comment: I realized giving the cordova command was pointless as you meant `npm -version` I invoked that and got 1.3.14 for `node --version` v0.10.22 I just tried following that stackoverflow post by changing versions and it still gave the error.

Comment: Can I generate an android project in eclipse then copy it into the .cordova folder?

Comment: No, don't copy anything into the .cordova folder - leave it alone. Can you please show us your $PATH environment variable? Also, have you created an AVD before? It shouldn't be necessary but maybe creating it generates some files Cordova needs. Can you do "android" in any folder/path on your system? Also, run `cordova platform add android -d` so we can see more debug information.

Comment: Yeah that was a good idea I did run that command and saw the error, I couldn't figure out specifically what it was, but doing what I said above (system restore) helped.. Working good now...