# Why is phonegap unable to run the wp8 emulator?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm on phonegap 3.7 and I'm trying to launch the emulator via:

```
phonegap run wp8
```

But if fails with:

> Error: Invalid target device specified.
>
> [..]
>
> ERROR: Error code -2147024809 for command: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs \Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\Xap
>   Deployment\XapDeployCmd.exe with args: /installlau
>   nch,C:/Users/kitsunde/Development/pub_pure_app/src/platforms/wp8/Bin/debug/Cordo
>   vaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap,/targetdevice:xd
>
> Error:
>   C:\Users\kitsunde\Development\pub_pure_app\src\platforms\wp8\cordova\run.
>   bat: Command failed with exit code 2
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\kitsunde\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
>   \phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.j
>   s:135:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)

What could be causing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Cordova/PhoneGap 3.6, if you are trying to emulate Windows Phone 8.1, you have to use the `windows` platform in Cordova/PhoneGap rather than the `wp8` platform.

```
phonegap platforms rm wp8
phonegap platforms add windows
```

> The Apache Cordova 3.6 release has been inspired by the idea of Building universal Windows apps. It introduces a new unified ‘windows’ platform to build apps targeting Windows 8.0, Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. Note, Windows Phone 8.0 still remains as a separate ‘wp8’ platform due to different implementation.

from: http://akvelon.com/apache-cordova-adds-windows-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1-universal-apps-support/

Got that?

- Windows 8 > use `windows` platform
- Windows 8.1 > use `windows` platform
- Windows Phone 8 > use `wp8` platform
- Windows Phone 8.1 > use `windows` platform

If you really just want to emulate Windows Phone 8, you probably need to install the Windows Phone 8 sdk if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

It seem the `run wp8` command does not specify the target model of the emulator.
You can navigate to `platforms/wp8` folder and open the solution file (`.sln` file).

Then you can run your project with a emulator model, which you want.

Comment: So I open the .sln file . . . now what?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [workaround](http://tiku.io/questions/903805/trying-to-run-phonegap-wp8-app-in-emulator-fails-msbuild-failed-to-compile-cord) and also to fix the issue you could have a look at this.

[Cordova/PhoneGap cannot add WP7/WP8/Windows platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792936/)